# Multiple simultaneous HTTP requests using .NET networking libraries

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking, asynchronous

I have a number of devices (IP cameras) in dedicated LAN segment, connected to PC. Devices support individual JPEG frames transfers using HTTP protocol. 
I need to send HTTP requests to all devices simultaneously, as far as possible. Getting images back can take different times, it makes no difference. Few milliseconds between first and last request on modern mid-level CPU would be nice. (I know, that I'm using non-realtime system).

The peak data transfer rate of the devices is about 50 Mbps, PC connection to LAN segment is 1000Mbps. The number of devices is about ten. Typical size of HTTP request is about 150 bytes, response is 40..200 Kbytes.

Now I use `DownloadDataAsync` method of `WebClient` class, one instance of it for every device. But is there more efficient methods?

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient?  Is `DownloadDataAsync` not meeting your need?

Comment: For example, using `HttpWebRequest` takes less time (about 10%) for entire request-response. Also, some `WebClient` behavior depends on Internet Explorer settings. But most important thing is minimum delay between multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself: HttpWebRequest is slightly faster because it has lower overhead. Going faster than that will be hard to achieve, though.

Edit: Of course, you could use raw Sockets to drive the HTTP protocol. That is going to be a lot of work, though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion about raw sockets, I will try to use `Socket` class with `BeginConnect`/`BeginSend` async methods.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on the way the cameras work and the network layout...

you can use Multicast Sockets:
[article 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C)
[article 2](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=409)

which are most efficient..

if your LAN is small in size (roughly consist solely of the cameras and controllers) 
you can use broadcast,  but this will gain very little vs. multicast (only some Router Processing time)

Comment: For some reasons I limited now to use HTTP protocol. Cameras support UDP protocol, but with some issues (not sure about multicast).